# Run python script against open app on my Android device w/o restarting app

Tags: python, android, webdriver, appium

I want to attach a session to an already running app on my Android phone. FYI: I do not have the APK of this app.

With the `try / except` I implemented it keeps restarting the app first and therefore cannot find `HomeActivity` and then crashes.

I need this in order to inspect my screen with `appium-desktop` for example, but at least I don't want to have to restart the app and just continue from the current state.

Is there a flag to start webdriver execution from the **current** state of the phone and look for the desired activity, i.e. in this case `HomeActivity` from the `DESIRED_CAPS_HOME`?

```py
try:
  driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', DESIRED_CAPS_HOME)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  except Exception:
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', DESIRED_CAPS_SPLASH)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

```py
DESIRED_CAPS_SPLASH = {
    'platformName': 'Android',
    'platformVersion': '8',
    'deviceName': 'Samsung A5 (2017)',
    'appPackage': 'com.appname',
    'appActivity': 'com.appname.SplashActivity',
    'noReset': True,
    'fullReset': False,
    'waitForReady': True,
}
```

```py
DESIRED_CAPS_HOME = {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "8",
    "deviceName": "Samsung A5 (2017)",
    "appPackage": "com.appname",
    "appActivity": "com.appname.HomeActivity",
    "noReset": True,
    "fullReset": False,
    "waitForReady": True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- This link helps you to get the current session and reusing of it.
  You can find something similar to this on appium also because it uses the same library

https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/